# Jest testing , How to write a test for a method that includes react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme, next.js

I have a simple Authentication component. I need to know what is the best approach to testing the `isLogin` method. I store details of the user in redux-store and whenever I call this method it checks store and returns true or false. here is the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import type { Node } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Render } from '..';

type componentProps = {
  fallback?: any,
  children: Array<Node> | Node,
};

/* A method for checking if user is login or not */
const isLogin = () => {
  const token = useSelector(state => state.User.token);

  return !!token;
};

const Authentication = ({ fallback, children }: componentProps) => {
  const token = useSelector(state => state.User.token);
  return [
    <Render key="item-auth-children" condition={token}>
      {children}
    </Render>,
    <Render key="item-auth-fallback" condition={!token && fallback}>
      {fallback}
    </Render>,
  ];
};

Authentication.defaultProps = {
  fallback: null,
};

Authentication.isLogin = isLogin;

export default Authentication;
```

I need to write a test with jest- enzyme to check isLogin method.

I did something like this but it doesn't make any sense:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Authentication } from '..';

const middleWares = [];
const mockStore = configureStore(middleWares);

const initialState = {
  User: {
    loading: false,
    token: '',
    userType: 'client',
    error: {},
  },
};
const store = mockStore(initialState);

describe('isLogin Method test', () => {
  it('should checks user login state correctly', function() {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>{Authentication.isLogin()}</Provider>,
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Might be relevant (shows how to write tests by using mocked auth), even it utilizes Auth0, it is pretty related to your case: https://itnext.io/how-to-mock-auth0-spa-hooks-to-test-your-react-components-e45b6a38fddb?gi=b50acdfcfe50

Comment: That reference to `itnext.io` is no longer valid. It uses a file `react-auth0-wrapper` that is nowhere to be found the Auth0 sample apps.